# Calculate probability from a table

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame as following:

```
current state   action  next state
w                 1      w
w                 1      w
w                 1      o
w                 1      o
o                 1      w
```

I want to create a matrix to show that how much is probability of been in next state by taking action1. 
The martix  that I want to have is as following:

```
          next.state
current    o    w  Sum
   w       0.5 0.5  1.00
   o       0   1.00 1.00
```

Comment: `addmargins(prop.table(table(dat$current, dat$next.state), 1), 2)`

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please tell me what does 1 and 2 mean in the addmargins(, ,1),2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)

df <- dcast(df, 
            current_state ~ next_state, 
            fun.aggregate = length)

df[, 2:ncol(df)] <- df[, 2:ncol(df)] / rowSums(df[, 2:ncol(df)])
df$Sum <- rowSums(df[, 2:ncol(df)])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a good way is to use `CrossTable` from `gmodels` for this:

```
library(gmodels)
tab <- CrossTable(df$current_state, df$next_state)
```

This will be printed on screen:

```
Total Observations in Table:  5 


                 | df$next_state 
df$current_state |         o |         w | Row Total | 
-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
               o |         0 |         1 |         1 | 
                 |     0.400 |     0.267 |           | 
                 |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.200 | 
                 |     0.000 |     0.333 |           | 
                 |     0.000 |     0.200 |           | 
-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
               w |         2 |         2 |         4 | 
                 |     0.100 |     0.067 |           | 
                 |     0.500 |     0.500 |     0.800 | 
                 |     1.000 |     0.667 |           | 
                 |     0.400 |     0.400 |           | 
-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
    Column Total |         2 |         3 |         5 | 
                 |     0.400 |     0.600 |           | 
-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

And you can also get just the probabilities by doing:

```
tab <- CrossTable(df$current_state, df$next_state)$prop.row

> tab
   y
x     o   w
  o 0.0 1.0
  w 0.5 0.5
```

And for completion:

```
tab <- CrossTable(df$current_state, df$next_state)$prop.row
tab <- as.data.frame.matrix(tab)
tab$Sum <- rowSums(tab)

> tab
    o   w Sum
o 0.0 1.0   1
w 0.5 0.5   1
```

Comment: but it is not true, because the probability of first row is not 1 and it is 0.2 but in each row the total probability should be 1. and number of elements is not important to be shown. The cumulative probability of each row should be 1.

Comment: The row total column shows the percentage of o and w in current state. you ve got 1 o and 4 w in current state which translates to 0.2 and 0.8 respectively. The cummulative probability is 1 but it is not shown. You can use the second part to get the probabilities i.e. `tab <- CrossTable(df$current_state, df$next_state)$prop.row` and if you really need the cummulative probability to be shown just add the two columns. They will always be 1

Comment: Thanks now I understood. Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

try this (using base R):

```
dat <- data.frame(cur_state = c('w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'o'), next_state = c('w', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'w'))
tmp <- table(dat[, 'cur_state'], dat[, 'next_state'])
tmp/rowSums(tmp)

#   o   w
# o 0.0 1.0
# w 0.5 0.5
```